# Is Visual Studio 2010 beta 1 usable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I saw that Beta 1 of VS2010 was publicly availible.

My question to those of you who has tried it is: does it work good?

Will it cause my computer to blow up in tiny pieces? Will it crash randomly? Will it work with some minor glitches? Or is it just perfect from bottom up?

I'm only coding school- and hobby-stuff, so nothing that someones life depend upon, but i still want software that works. How close to a final product is it? Is it worth trying?

Comment: Does it come with F# or IronPython?

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit slow, and there's no offline MSDN, but it's worth trying IMO. Having said that it's slow, I still use it on my NC10 netbook, so it's clearly not *that* bad :)

I've got it side-by-side VS2008, and that hasn't caused any problems.

I've seen a couple of glitches (once the keyboard handling went completely wonky) but it's certainly usable. The main question is what you want to get out of trying it - in my case I absolutely need to code against C# 4 to explore the new features. I do most of that from the command line in fact, where the speed of VS obviously isn't an issue, but it's nice to see the VS-specific features as well (like the debug threading views for Parallel Extensions).

Comment: apart from the iper-promoted parallel extension debugging, the simplified office automation integration from c# and the new c# dynamic keyword, are there some (minor) vs-specific or c# 4.0 that are noteworthy?

Comment: Named/optional arguments and generic variance spring to mind. There's code contracts in .NET 4.0 as well - I don't know which bucket you want to put those into :)

Comment: I'd just like to add that Parallel Lib is available on .NET 4.0 too and it should be more than enough for justifying its use :)

Comment: code contract like eiffel require/ensure? **this** sound good!

Comment: Sort of. It's done with a library rather than language changes, but it hooks into the build system. See http://research.microsoft.com/contracts

Comment: Thanks, seems very interesting, when I've got a bit of time I will test it against linFu / PostSharp AOP frameworks to see pro and cons of each solution ;)

Comment: The contract stuff isn't finished in the beta, but some of it's there.  :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems more or less usable on the .NET side. The C++ side is a bit more sketchy. On one hand, they've added support for some very nice new C++0x features, on the other, they've broken some absolute fundamentals.

Your plain old `main` function won't compile in 32-bit with unicode enabled. (Workarounds: Either compile as 64-bit, disable unicode, or rename the function to `wmain`).

This seems to me to be a strong hint that the C++ side of things is nowhere near release-worthy. I'd probably wait for beta2 before doing any serious work with that.

Comment: Even better: _tmain is going to work both as Unicode and as ANSI app.
But if your application was never before compiled as Unicode, main is the last of your worries. I am ready to bet there is a lot of work to do beyond that.

Comment: _tmain is not standard. Standard C++ has one entry point, named "main". _tmain works for unicode and ansi on MSVC, yes, but it fails on all other compilers. That's hardly a solution, and Unicode compatibility has nothing to do with it. All my apps use Unicode, and they all use main, not wmain or _tmain.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is great, but the performance hurts a bit.

Here is an idea for you:  Install it into a VirtualPC.  Then you can play and not care what it does.  You don't like it, delete the VPC image and keep on trucking.  That is how I play with Microsoft betas now.  I never install them on any real machine - too risky.

Answer (score 1):

**Usable**: Yes.

**Recommended**: Not if you'r a touchpad-addict or dislike crashing apps.

I've been trying it for 2 weeks now coding small C#-projects and these are my impressions

**Reasons to use 2010:**

- Looks good
- Multi monitor support
- I can see myself using the code templating but right now i couldnt find any really useful stuff except for reducing the fontsize of comments.
- Zoom in the editor
- Select a variable and then press shift+up/down to go to next usage of this variable
- Ctrl+, brings up instant search of classes and functions in the entire project. (i've become really addicted to this)
- Floating watches for single objects

**Reasons to not use 2010:**

- TOUCHPAD SCROLL DOESN'T WORK IN THE EDITOR!!! (this is reason enough to not upgrade if you are using it on a laptop)
- I've had some random app-crashes in the middle of just writing code, once or twice per day maybe.
- UI sometimes freezes randomly for about 30seconds and then returns to normal.
- It started to use 100% CPU power from one of my cores once when it was minimized in basic editing-mode and i was doing other stuff in other programs, i only noticed it because the fan started to go wild.

Otherwhise it's pretty similar to 2008. I haven't noticed any difference in speed like other people say.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about Ctrl+, - hoorah, my favourite feature from Eclipse and R# has *finally* gone into mainstream VS. It's about time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself: what is the advantage for *you* in using VS2010 over VS2008? I would suggest that there is no advantage if all you are doing is "school- and hobby-stuff".

I'm still using VS2008 for business related stuff (and, indeed, VC6 for some stuff). I prefer to wait until all the early adopters have tested it (and Microsoft has released at least one service pack *after* the real product release) before I do their testing for them.

Comment: Hmm, catch22, i don't know if there are any advantages if i haven't tried it :D

Comment: That is a good point, but life's too short for me to do Microsoft's testing for no pay. I prefer to spend that time doing my own stuff, let everyone else do MS' testing then upgrade once it's a polished product. My customers don't care at all what tools I use as long as their software works. I *will* keep abreast of what's in a new release (based on marketing docs and web reviews) but sometimes I'll even skip versions if they don't offer enough advantage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to co-exist with other versions of VS without causing any problems.

Regarding the slowness - it seems to be the UI that is slow, rather than building. Once it's going it doesn't seem much slower on my fast quadcore. I've yet to try it on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It's usable enough, the small glitches that I've encounter weren't that bad. However, certain VS extensions(like XNA) don't work in VS2010 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's fun to toy with. Not usable for me, cause re#er does not support it yet (had to install TestDriven .NET which works through keyboard shortcuts only to run my tests).

Gave me an insight how addicted I am. :/

Btw, on Win7, without virtual pc it seemed even faster than vs2008 for me.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 doesn't yet support mobile device projects, which might or might not matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ wise - VS2010 has a built-in 64-bit compiler, VS2008 does not.

You can supposedly add 64-bit support to VS2008, but it takes some effort.

Comment: 2008 comes with a 64-bit compiler too. You just have to select it during install.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using VS 2010 beta (with .NET 4.0 beta) on Windows 7 RC.  I've been trying to rewrite parts of a large-scale business application in it to see what can be done with it.

The UI freezes frequently.  I'm talking 1-10 minutes between freezes.  The UI does not come back, so I'm forced to kill devenv.exe every time it happens.  Microsoft probably puts my error reports in their spam folder by now.

For me, VS 2010 beta 1 classifies as unusable.  However, it's fast, the new IDE functions are very handy, and it's pretty.  I keep coming back to it despite my resolutions to wait for a stable build.